# Changing my tab bar color without a xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm facing trouble changing my tab bar color because i didn't use a xib file and somehow my code structure isn't helping me at all, tell me if i need to rewrite the whole thing from scratch however i'll be very appreciating if i didn't have to ^_^

This is my appDelegate file of a single view app and here i create the tab bar with a navigation bar associated to each tab and then displaying them

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

self.firstTab = [[FirstTab alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
self.firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.firstTab];
self.thirdTab = [[ThirdTab alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
self.thirdNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.thirdTab];
self.tab2 = [[newsecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newsecViewController" bundle:NULL];
self.tab2NavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.tab2];
self.tab2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];



//NSArray *tabs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.firstTab, self.secondTab, self.thirdTab, nil];
NSArray *tabBars = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.firstNavigationController, self.tab2NavigationController, self.thirdNavigationController, nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tabBars];
[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

This is a code sample for one of my tabs

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if(self != nil) {
    self.title = @"Second";
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"triangle.png"];

}
return self;
```

Thanks all for your help...

Comment: Which color do you wish to change? The overall color of all of the tabs or the tint of the selected tab image? Which version(s) of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Use tabbar's tintColor property. It's available in iOS 5.0 and later.

```
[tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Comment: Under iOS 7 the `tintColor` sets the color of the image of the selected tab. Use `barTintColor` under iOS 7 to tint the actual tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with iOS 7, when setting the color of `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar` use the `barTintColor` property.

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```